# Docker produces 'port already allocated' when IP address is specified in port definition

Tags: ubuntu, docker

I've run into a strange issue with docker.

`sudo docker run -d -p 54.201.110.30:80:80 image`

results in

> 2015/02/03 23:36:28 Error response from daemon: Cannot start container 86eea21e1a83a115fdf77c87303f94d56dd5ed4f07fb946d8abea85532761f28: port has already been allocated

While

`sudo docker run -d -p 80:80 image`

works just fine. The port 80 on the host is free (checked with `netstat -l`).

Any ideas what can be a reason?

Comment: Weird, are you sure 54.201.110.30 is the correct IP on your server? Maybe there's a bug in the error reporting.

Comment: This is probably because you didn't exit docker properly the previous time.  In OSX I run `boot2docker down` to kill docker if this happens.  You should then be able to run it normally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is IP address was not being assigned to the host.

Answer (score 1):

I experience similar but occasional "port has already been allocated" issues on Fedora 20.

`service docker restart` or `systemctl restart docker` generally fixes intermittent startup problems. I've never experienced this issue on CoreOS and it seems to have gone away with v1.4.

You should also add your user to the `docker` group instead of using `sudo`. Don't forget groups are applied at login, so you may have to log out and back in again to see your group updated.